# Word for property damage

Tags: single-word-requests, legalese

I am currently working on a fictitious legal system and am looking for a single word for *property damage*. I could not find a legal term that fits, though you may know of better resources than I.
It would be ideal if it were a noun so it could be placed in the following context: "The accused committed an act of ..."

Any and all suggestions would be welcome and I hope you enjoy the challenge.

Comment: Not a single word, but in common law _trespass to chattels_ is a civil action to claim damages when your personal property has been damaged or destroyed by another. Unlike most torts (civil wrongs), it is an intentional tort: deliberate action is required but only the touching of the chattel must be deliberate. It's a nice phrase, though, with a good old legal air to it. (For wrongful taking, the action is called _trover_, and to recover something taken the action is _replevin_.)

Comment: It does have a nice ring, where is it from? Britain?

Comment: Originally, England. It's gone where the common law's gone, which is all the places where the English went, stayed and stole.

Comment: Legal terminology is always specific to a particular legal system. If you are creating a fictional legal system, it is up to you to create its terminology in whatever way suits your literary purposes.

Comment: What would be wrong with simple "damage" even in English? Here, you say you're working on a legal system, which stops it being about English per se, and a fictitious legal system at that, which suggests you might find more help somewhere like SE Writing or Worldbuilding. At the end of the day why not either invent a fictitious word, or give up trying to force a single word to do something the real legal system hasn't done in how many centuries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In common law, in the case of real property (i.e. land), **waste** is used.

According to the [relevant definition in the legal dictionary at Dictionary.com](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=2239):

> **waste**
>
> *n.* 1) any damage to real property by a tenant which lessens its value to the landlord, owner or future owner. An owner can sue for damages for waste, terminate a lease of one committing waste and/or obtain an injunction against further waste.

Essentially, *waste* is unauthorised changes made to the land. *Waste* describes the damage and cause of action but *waste* doesn't necessarily involve a criminal act. Also *waste* is *waste* whether it was caused deliberately or not.

Technically, the definition given above isn't 100% accurate and *waste* can actually *improve* the land, but in these cases it is distinguished as *[ameliorative waste](https://definitions.uslegal.com/a/ameliorative-waste/).*

However, its precise meaning in common law would not matter for your purposes - I presume you just want some kind of real-world hook to hang the concept on - *waste* would have sufficient verisimilitude, is conveniently general and also has a nice, harsh condemnatory ring to it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep it in mind but was looking for something that could also be used for other property e.g. a watch. Really nice work though, certainly very helpful.

Comment: Then there's the interesting expression: "to lay waste," from which comes "laid waste," as in "The destructive tenant laid waste to what was once a lovely apartment."

Comment: @ALambentEye If you're constructing a fictional legal system, you can do whatever you want... that is, if you like the word! It helps that in this instance the term isn't really known outside of legal circles.

Comment: @tmgr Touché. XD

Comment: The OP's example of a sentence in which the term is to be used suggests that what is sought is a term of criminal law, not of the law of property.

Comment: @jsw29 Sure, and that proviso is in the answer. But OP also want a word that, put in common law terms, cuts across civil and criminal law (and possibly covering both real and personal property), as they want accidental damage to be covered as well as deliberate. Beyond _damage_ and _injury_, which are really, really nonspecific, I don't think there is one term that covers them and it's a case of finding something that can be adapted to fit into their fictional legal system.

Answer (score 8):

*vandalism* could work, if the damage is done on purpose:

> : willful or malicious destruction or defacement of public or private property

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vandalism))</sub>

Comment: +1 and I guess a fictitious legal system could be constructed so as to make no distinction between willful and accidental/ careless property damage.

Comment: Although a valid response, I was looking for a more exotic term. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 4):

Prior to construction surveyors carry  out a **[dilapidation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilapidation)** survey

Primarily used for structures or land it can also be used for rentals, objects and people [dilapidated tramp](http://www.workhouses.org.uk/Higgs/TrampAmongTramps.shtml) so for a watch we see it used by [professionals here as in,](https://www.ashtontracy.ca/horological-insider/official-service-center-vs-independent-who-should-you-choose-part-1)

"Restoration requires, time, patience and skill to breath new life into a **dilapidated watch** that has been neglected."

A similar concept is **dereliction** that is not just for duty, in legalise it is similarly neglected.