# Word for breach of privacy

Tags: single-word-requests, legalese

I am currently working on a fictitious legal system and am now looking for a single word describing a ***breach of privacy***, in the sense of a **home invasion** but also, if possible, **indecent exposure** (as in a breach of one's own privacy).

I could (unsurprisingly) not find a legal term that fits.

It would be ideal if it were a noun so it could be placed in the following context:

> The accused committed an act of _____

I am aware of the fact that a fictitious system would allow for any word, but am curious to hear you response.

Any and all suggestions would be welcome and I hope you enjoy the challenge.

Comment: Indecent exposure is a public offense. You can be naked within your own four walls unless you, say, parade about in front of your front window, thus making it public.

Comment: I agree, but no-one would 'tell' if it weren't public.

Comment: Maybe **trespassing**!

Comment: Privacy and modesty can both be ***compromised***

Comment: @Jim Well spotted!

Comment: The word *deprivacy*, normally still found in quotes as a nonce word, nevertheless has quite a healthy usage history. "15:15 – 16:00 Carl Mitcham, Colorado School of Mines
- Privacy vs deprivacy: The shifting social values of public exposures

Comment: The same comment can applied to this question as to the OP's [earlier one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477246): if one is creating a fictional legal system, one can create its terminology however one pleases. There cannot be a definite, authoritative answer to this question, as there is no established legal terminology for a legal system that does not exist. If the question is asking for help in *creating* it, then it belongs to the domain of fiction writing, not of exploring the *existing* usage of English language.

Comment: @jsw29 I understand, but am nevertheless looking for real words. How does my query differ from another single-word-request, where one asks "What is the most appropriate word for this case?" when referring to real terms?

Comment: The problem is not with the fictional context. The problem is that SE is collecting definitive answers to questions about the English language. That is, we're writing the English FAQ. As written, this is not an FAQ. It's a request for ideas or suggestions. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with such questions, but they're not a good fit for what we're doing here.

Comment: Sometimes a word request can be made to fit with what SE is doing. As a site, we've decided that a word request fits when it is (i) well researched and contains details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why; and, (ii) includes the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provides the exact enclosing sentence or passage. You're part of the way there already, so you might be able to do this with your question.

Comment: If you conclude that you really do have a subjective question rather than an English FAQ, you're always welcome to visit our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95) and raise it there.

Comment: @MetaEd Thank you for pointing it out, I shall do my best to improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few words that mean *breach of privacy*:

***Contravention***

*An action which offends against a law, treaty, or other ruling.*

***Encroachment***

*Intrusion on a person's territory, rights, etc.*

***Infraction***

*A violation or infringement of a law or agreement.*

***Infringement***

*The action of breaking the terms of a law, agreement, etc.; violation.*

***Offense***

A breach of a law or rule; an illegal act.

***Transgression***

*An act that goes against a law, rule, or code of conduct; an offence.*

And obviously *violation*, but it has been mentioned before.  My best picks from this list are *Contravention*, *Infringement* and *Infraction*, because (I think, at least) are the closest in meaning to 'breach of privacy'.

> *Hacking the system is an infringement of our privacy.*

**All definitions taken from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/).**

Comment: Some very nice suggestions! It would be nice if you could add the definitions under the individual word, just so it's immediately clear.

Comment: Sure!  Editing right now.

Comment: There you go!  Done

Comment: A beauty to the eyes...

Comment: Now what should I interpret that as... extortion? ;)

I appear in fact to be even newer than you, and so am eager to support, but I'd rather sit it out a little to see what else pops up, don't worry about it.

Comment: Just FYI, the dictionary you got the definitions from is "Oxford Dictionaries", not "the Oxford English Dictionary" (which is a completely different dictionary). Please see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128233611/http://public.oed.com/about/the-oed-and-oxford-dictionaries/) if you need more info on what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The word *Violation* seems appropriate but several others might do.

The accused committed a *violation* of decency by exposing himself.
The plaintiffs rights/privacy was *violated* by the accused.

Comment: I agree, but couldn't a violation be more-or-less anything illegal, as in a violation of the law?

Comment: Yes, violation is used for any illegal (or perceived illegal) action. I'm trying to think of one word choices per the request. An Offence would be such a single word.